# Transit in Korea

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, south-korea, vietnam

I'm Vietnamese and now studying in the US. I also have a Vietnamese passport and US visa. If I come from San Francisco to Vietnam and I have to transit in Korea 3 days, can I go outside to travel with 3 days, then come back to Korea airport, and go to my country - Vietnam ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=sgn&DE=sgn&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=icn&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Nationals of any country with a visa issued by the USA if in transit through
>     Korea (Rep.) if: 
>     -holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within
>     30 days; when
>     -arriving from the country that issued the visa (a visa that
>     expired on departure from that country is accepted) and
>     departing to a third country.

So yes, you can enter South Korea by presenting your passport and connecting flight ticket and stay for max 30 days